# MySQL issue updating DATETIME Field from ISO 8601 format

Tags: mysql, datetime, str-to-date

I have a table with a varchar field that contains ISO 8601 time format like 2015-01-18t10:00:10z.

I can use

```
select STR_TO_DATE('2015-01-18t10:00:10z','%Y-%m-%dt%H:%i:%s')
```

and get the correct result:

> 2015-01-18 10:00:10

When I come to use this to insert into a DATETIME field I get:

```
update test set optin1 = STR_TO_DATE(optin,'%Y-%m-%dt%H:%i:%s')
```

> Error Code: 1292
>   Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2015-01-18t10:00:10z'

`Optin` is the varchar ISO 8601 time column

`Optin1` is the DATETIME field I want to update.

Anyone know why this is hapepenig and how to fix the issue?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the 'z' to your pattern,

```
update test set optin1 = STR_TO_DATE(optin,'%Y-%m-%dt%H:%i:%sz')
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea601/1